# What type of data is used for CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand CNN and how it works. I have a very basic question. Having downloaded a dataset from kaggle, it has two folders of test and train with several images in it. It also has a csv file with the images names in it and with a tag '1' and '0'. So my confusion is whether to load the images from train folder or the csv or both?

Comment: The image is the input, the 0 or 1 the output.

Comment: For example, if your images are a bunch of cats and dogs, thenyou are trying to predict whether `image1` is the positive class `1` or the negative class, `0`.  (Depending on the setup, `1`/`0` will be either be `cat`/`not a cat` or `dog`/`not a dog` in this example)

Answer (score 0):

**training set**

> A training dataset is a dataset of examples used for learning, that is
>   to fit the parameters (e.g., weights) of, for example, a classifier.

---

**test set**

> A test set is therefore a set of examples used only to assess the
>   performance (i.e. generalization) of a fully specified classifier.

*[from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets#Training_dataset)*

While you want to **train** image classifier to recognize 0 or 1 class, with supervised learning methods, you need to show **image** data and **related class** (csv file data) as practice for model.

Then while **testing** model accuracy use data that model has never seen.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dataset like this

```
..train/
    ../img1.jpg
    ../img2.jpg
    ../img3.jpg
    ..........
    ../imgn.jpg

..test/
    ../test1.jpg
    ../test2.jpg
    ../test3.jpg
    ............
    ../testn.jpg
```

Also, you have a `train.csv` file with data like this

```
file_name    label
img1.jpg       0
img2.jpg       0
img3.jpg       1
img4.jpg       1
.......
.......
imgn.jpg       0
```

In order to train a CNN model in supervised manner, you need to have a labelled dataset in the from

```
image1 - label1
image2 - label2
image3 - label3
image4 - label4
```

In your `/train/` folder you have the images, their corresponding labels are provided in the `train.csv` file.

So you have to load the image data from `\train\` folder and corresponding label from the `csv` file.

In python you can do this easily like this assuming your image is `.jpg`,

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# function to read image using opencv
def read_img(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300))
    return img

# path for the folder with train images
TRAIN_PATH = 'train_img/'

# reading train.csv file
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

# reading the image data 
train_img = []
for img_path in tqdm(train['file_name'].values):
    train_img.append(read_img(TRAIN_PATH + img_path + '.jpg'))

# assigning labels from the csv file
train_label = train['label'].tolist()
```

I used `tqdm` to get a neat progress bar to indicate the progress of the operation, if the dataset it so huge it will be painful without a progress bar to know the progress, time left etc.